# Is the following extension of finite state automata studied?

Tags: finite-automata

Consider a finite state machine as usual, but every transition, it can also update an integer counter by adding or subtracting a number.
Say, a transition function of the form
$\delta(q,a) = (p,k)$
moves to the new state $p$, and add $k$ to the counter, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (so $k$ can be positive, negative, or zero).

A string is accepted if the final state and the counter value is in $F$, where $F$ is a finite set of pairs of states and counter values.

Is this model known? I could not find any reference of this particular extension.

Comment: Depends on the possible values of $k$. Can $k$ be negative?

Comment: $k$ can be negative.

Comment: A related question: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7574/which-languages-are-recognized-by-one-counter-machines

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming $k$ can be any integer, then this can be formalized as a *blind one-counter automaton*. Usually these automata accept on final state when its counter is zero, but we can easily model your acceptance type if you allow $\epsilon$ transitions (that do not consume input). If I am not mistaken, like with finite state automata, one can get rid of the $\epsilon$, but that is a non-trivial result.

There are several types of one-counter automata. In the most general form they are allowed to test whether the value of the counter equals zero. 
The languages they accept are a strict subset of the context-free languages.

The model you are probably looking for is called *blind*, it cannot test for zero, except as the final test for acceptance at the end of the computation.

Comment: "Counter" may be misleading, since in one-counter machines you can also branch the run according to the value of the counter (i.e. zero-tests), which makes the model very different (and much stronger).

Comment: You are right. I add some words on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

This model is a variant of weighted automata, which are widely studied (although there are a lot of open questions about them).
You can start here:
[Handbook of Weighted Automata](http://www.springer.com/la/book/9783642014918).

Note that sometimes they are called "distance automata" (although this is becoming less common).