# Difference between Counter-machine and stack machine

Tags: formal-languages, computability, automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

I read from this [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7574/which-languages-are-recognized-by-one-counter-machines) that counter automata is a push down automata with only one symbol allowed on the stack (plus a fixed bottom symbol).

My question is counter machine means counter coexist with stack? I mean "DFA $+ 1$ counter" is same thing with  "DFA $+1$ stack" . For example to generate this language $\{a^n b^n \mid n\geq 0\}$ we need counter + stack.

I also from that question **Languages recognized by one counter automata form a proper subset of the context free languages.**
What does it mean? Could you give one example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recognize $\{a^nb^n\}$ with just a counter (which is incremented by an $a$ and decremented by a $b$). No additional stack is needed. (If you used a stack, it would only contain $a$s; in general a counter is functionally equivalent to a stack whose alphabet consists of only one symbol.)

The answer to the question you link to provides an example of a deterministic context free language which cannot be recognised by a one-counter automaton: $\{a^nb^ma^mb^n\}$.

Comment: But "proper subset of the context free languages." this is not understanding.. Give one example which proper is what

Comment: @punia: $A$ is a proper subset of $B$ means that everything in $A$ is also in $B$, but at least one thing in $B$ is not in $A$. The answer gives an example of such a thing.

Comment: This is possible $\{a^nb^m\}$ could be proper subset of $\{a^nb^ma^mb^n\}$ ?

Comment: @punia: that's not what this is about (although it's true). The claim is that the set of languages recognisable with a one-counter automaton is a subset of the set of languages recognisable with a context-free grammar. It says nothing about individual languages in those sets. (A set of languages is a set of sets.)

Comment: please could you explain with example.. I am struggling to understand.. Please

Comment: @punia: there is a perfect example in the answer. You are confusing languages with sets of languages. You need to try to understand the difference. I don't know how to say it more simply. I'm sorry.

Comment: Understood ... Thank you..